# JSON building functions produce numeric values with trailing zeros after division

Tags: postgresql

Next json functions produce values with trailing zeros and the question is how to avoid it?

```
SELECT JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('a', (1::NUMERIC / 10));
SELECT JSONB_SET('{}'::JSONB, '{a}', (1::NUMERIC / 10)::TEXT::JSONB);
```

The oputput is

```
{"a": 0.10000000000000000000}
```

And it is observed only after division, for example, the next function produces the result without zeros

```
SELECT JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('a', 0.1::NUMERIC); -- {"a" : 0.1}
```

Division without json function works the same

```
SELECT 1::NUMERIC / 10;-- 0.1
```

If it matters, Postgres version is 10.5

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: No consequences after I read this JSON from DB and convert to my model, but it looks weird when I perform queries from sql CLI. And I'm not sure, but maybe this kind of format with trailing zeros consumes extra space in storage

Comment: What about using ```round()```?

Comment: @marcus `round()` gives you `0` instead of `0.1`

Comment: round(0.10000000000000000000, 20) doesn't...

Comment: round is used for different things - to leave the required number numbers after point
`SELECT JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('a', ROUND(1::NUMERIC / 10, 20)); --{"a": 0.10000000000000000000}
`

Answer (score 0):

It may be weird if you display a json value to the screen. Try convert number to double precision and then back to numeric, like:

```
SELECT JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('a', (1::NUMERIC / 10)::double precision::numeric);
SELECT JSONB_SET('{}'::JSONB, '{a}', (1::NUMERIC / 10)::double precision::numeric::TEXT::JSONB);
```